# http request AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

Hi I'm having a bit of a problem with my code I'm trying to test if this line of code(**ajaxmaprequest.js**)is working making it retrieve a string from **xmlspitquery.php** and echo it at testajax.php. Would appreciate any help on what I'm doing wrong.

**ajaxmaprequest.js**

```
$ ('#lgu','#category','#type').change(function(){
    var Lgu = $('#lgu').val();
    var Category = $('#category').val();
    var Type = $('#type').val();

    $.get('xmlspitquery.php',
         { input: Lgu, input2: Category, input3: Type}, 
         function(data) {
            $('#xmlreturn').text(data);
    });
});
```

And this is from testajax.php

```
<select id="lgu" name="Lgu">
    <option>LGUs</option>
    <option>Bacolod City</option>
    <option>Bago City</option>
    <option>Cadiz City</option>
</select>

<select id="category" name="Category">
    <option>Categories</option>
    <option>Hotel</option>
    <option>Restaurant</option>
    <option>Attractions</option>
</select>

<select id="type" name="Type">
    <option>Tourism Type</option>
    <option>Eco</option>
    <option>Resto</option>
    <option>Fun</option>
</select>

<div id="xmlreturn"> </div>
```

**xmlspitquery.php**

only has `echo "Test";` I will add more code once i get the connection done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
$('#lgu','#category','#type')
```

to this:

```
$('#lgu,#category,#type')
```

Comment: This fix is all that should be needed.. make sure its in a $(document).ready() block?

Comment: I put the js in external, should i add that?

Comment: Also I'm following a tutorial and at first modified what he did. Having problems, I did what he exactly did and still nothing.